# Spinner Android изменения цвета рамки

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

[image]]

У меня есть вот экран где несколько выпадающих списков
Когда выпадает весь список вокруг появляется черная рамка. как ее убрать или изменить ее цвет?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/transportType"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="2" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    style="@style/mySpinnerItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.2"
    android:backgroundTint="#1B385A"
    android:popupBackground="#1B385A" />
```

Весь остальной код стандартный.
в стиле спинера прописанно только TextColor

Comment: может это вам поможет - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231683/how-to-create-custom-spinner-like-border-around-the-spinner-with-down-triangle-o

Answer (score 0):

Нашел как исправить данную проблему.
добавить параметр в AppCompatSpinner

```
 android:popupElevation="0dp"
```